# Why right ctrl right shift doesn't align the text to the right?

Tags: html

> When I press right ctrl, I want the right shift the text will align
>   right.
>
> When I press left ctrl left shift the text will align left.
>
> It is not working.

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Where is the code that handles the keypress event for your input? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this in jQuery

Try pressing `ctrl + shift + right-arrow` on your keyboard. See what happens in the code snippet.

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 39) {
            $("p").css({"text-align": "right"});
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: its not supposed to be automtaic?

Comment: No, you can add the functionality using JS/jQuery though

Comment: i  see in sites that when you press  right ctrl right shift  the html attr is change dir="rtl" and not css